# How to extract an item from xml file with JQuery?

Tags: jquery, xml

I have an xml file in my server and a webpage that has to display a single element from that file. I thought i'd use JQuery since it has the tools for the job. Here is my script:

```
function loader()
{
    $(function() {
        $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url: "http://localhost/myfile.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(data) {
            xmlString = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(data);
            alert(xmlString);
            $xml = $( xmlString );
            $tool = $xml.find("tool");
            alert($tool.text());
        },
        error: function(xhr, status) {
            alert(status);
        }
    });
});
}

loader();
```

Here is the xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tool xmlns="http://example.com/hello" name="my_tool">
.
.
.
</tool>
```

I'm just trying to pull the "tool" element, and get the value of "name". However, when I try it, I get a blank response. When I run the same code on other inner elements, it works just fine. What's going on?

Answer (score 0):

This will get you the 'name' attribute value:

```
$tool.attr('name');
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to think of the XML as HTML.  `var val = $(theXML).find('tool').attr('name')`  Now that you have the xml loaded into jQuery, you can do all kinds of other cool selections too: `var xml = $(theXML); var children = xml.find('childElement'); children.forEach(function (item) {...`  It's awesome.

Comment: It works for other elements, but it does not work for 'tool'. It says 'undefined' when I try to print the name

Comment: Try this: `var dom = $('<div />'); dom.html(theXML); dom.find('tool')`